# SQL Query for all IDs where all rows with that ID match a value in another column

Tags: sql, select

I am trying to query data for all ID numbers where all rows with that ID number match some value in another column.

For example, query for IDs where all rows with that ID have the Color Blue.

Sample Table:

```
ID:     Color: 

1       Red 
1       Blue 

2       Blue 
2       Blue 

3       Blue
```

Desired query result: `ID: 2, 3`

We see that one row with `ID: 1` has `Color: Blue`, but another row with `ID: 1` has `Color: Red`, so it's not quite right.

If I just query for distinct IDs where Color = Blue, I see `ID: 1, 2, 3`

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_any_all.asp

Comment: @RobertHarvey -- This is not the same as the duplicate you linked to.  That only works because it's summing an integer field... This is a varchar and would error out with that approach...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option using `aggregation`:

```
select id
from yourtable
group by id
having max(color) = 'Blue' and min(color) = 'Blue'
```

Comment: @RobertHarvey Care to elaborate?  I would think this would outperform a `subquery` using `distinct`...

Comment: As the software developer coming in after you, I would find it difficult to divine the intent of this query.  Clarity always trumps performance, unless you really need the performance and are willing to document the sh*t out of this to alleviate my confusion.

Comment: Also, I'm not convinced that this is faster than a subquery.  `In` clauses against subqueries perform very fast; on SQL Server, they are the fastest possible way if you can satisfy their novel constraints.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I honestly don't know, my gut tells me the `correlated subquery` with `distinct` would be slower though.  I don't think you could do this with a simple `in` clause though because you need to `correlate` on the `id`.  You could use `exists` with `distinct`, but again, I'm not sure which would be faster without setting up multiple examples with different keys/etc and viewing the `execution plan`.  That's a little above my SO paygrade though!

Comment: @sgeddes . . . I think the intent is very clear, clearer than a correlated subquery with `select distinct`.

Comment: This did the trick! I love that it targets what I want instead of what I don't want. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A query like this:

```
select id
from test
group by id
having sum(case when color = 'Red' then 1 else 0 end) < 1;
```

SQLFiddle with demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0da93b/11

Comment: I would remove `color` from your `select` statement.  `mysql` allows for this and only returns an arbitrary value for it, but most other databases would require it to be included in your `group by` clause, and that wouldn't work.

Comment: This would work well for getting cases that only are not red. I was looking more to target the color "blue" in this example even if other colors exist in the set besides "blue" and "red." It was my bad for not giving a better example data set. Thank you!